# Exporting data from Couchbase to HDFS / Hadoop using Sqoop returns replicate data

Tags: hadoop, import, hdfs, couchbase, connector

Our data in couchbase is replicated so we have 2x of every record.
I use Sqoop plug-in, the Couchbase Hadoop Connector to import data from Couchbase to HDFS:

Here's my command:

**sqoop import --connect $server_address/pools --table DUMP --username data-db --num-mappers 10**

For example, if there are 3 records in couchbase:

a123, {last_name : Smith, age : 20}

b234, {last_name : Jones, age : 25}

c456, {last_name : Burke, age : 30}

After the import, I'll get

a123, {last_name : Smith, age : 20}

a123, {last_name : Smith, age : 20}

b234, {last_name : Jones, age : 25}

b234, {last_name : Jones, age : 25}

c456, {last_name : Burke, age : 30}

c456, {last_name : Burke, age : 30}

in HDFS.

This is very annoying as we have many millions of data, having 2x of everything doubles the run time. I really wish there's a way to get rid of the duplicates.

Thank you so much for any help or hint you can provide :)

-----> Also, if you read the documentation for the connector, one of the limitations is that you cannot **query** for specific data.